# Дистрибутив для разрабтки под QT

Tags: qt4, debian, linux

Собственно сабж - что порекомендуйте?

Ванильный/Сид Дебиан отпадает - там баг - изза гцц не работает правильно дебаг в креаторе.

Но с остальными не знаком - посоветуйте плиз...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну кубунта и федора с кедами вполне так просты в освоении

Comment: еще говорят, что в сусе кеды ниче так готовят

Answer (score 1):

Для разработки под QT первоначально выбрал Debian, но относительно быстро его снёс и поставил Arch Linux. Вполне доволен.

Comment: арч прекрасен - но тут нужны хорошие навыки линукс пользователя - коим я не являюсь - неофит я...

Comment: Я сам недавно стал изучать Linux - и начал изучать именно с Arch. Хорошая вики на оффсайте. Новые пакеты в репозиториях. Самое сложное было установить, но в Интернете есть примеры.